# ¿Por qué no me funciona la libreria animate.css?

Tags: html, css, animate.css

Estoy intentando aprender un poco de animaciones con la librería animate.css, pero no la puedo utilizar. Leí la documentación y agregué las dependencias a mi archivo `.html`, pero a la hora de dar clase a un texto para que sea animado, no pasa nada.

Adjunto el código html:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;1,100;1,200&display=swap");
:root {
  --violet:rgb(149, 57, 192);
  --green-arrow: rgb(65, 252, 65);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header .background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

header .background h1, header .background p, header .background button, header .background i {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

header .background p {
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 55%;
}

header .background i {
  top: 75%;
  color: var(--green-arrow);
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background">

                <h1 class="animate__bounce 2s infinite">Lorem, ipsum dolor</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down fa-3x "></i>
                


        </div>
    </header>



    <main>
        <div class="informacion">
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e9a72a7d64.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El texto que quiero animar, en este caso es el `<h1>`. ¿Alguno sabe cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Espero que mi respuesta se ha de ayuda. Primero, para usar animate.css su documentacion especifica lo siguiente:

> "Después de instalar Animate.css, agregue la clase animate__animated a
> un elemento, junto con cualquiera de los nombres de animación (¡no
> olvide el prefijo animate__!):".

Aplicando esto a tu codigo seria asi

```
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce animate__delay-2s animate__infinite ">Lorem, ipsum dolor</h1>
```

Para aplicar un delay, debes escribir la clase  animate__delay- + el tiempo en segundos. En tu codigo seria asi

```
animate__bounce animate__delay-2s
```

Por ultimo, para que la animacion se ha infinita, solo agrega la clase `animate__infinite`. Listo, tienes la animacion funcionando. Revisa el siguiente codigo para una mayor compresion.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;1,100;1,200&display=swap");
:root {
  --violet:rgb(149, 57, 192);
  --green-arrow: rgb(65, 252, 65);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header .background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

header .background h1, header .background p, header .background button, header .background i {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

header .background p {
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 55%;
}

header .background i {
  top: 75%;
  color: var(--green-arrow);
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background">

                <h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce animate__delay-2s animate__infinite">Lorem, ipsum dolor</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-down fa-3x "></i>
                


        </div>
    </header>



    <main>
        <div class="informacion">
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e9a72a7d64.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aunque copie y pegue tu clase, no me funciona

Comment: ` <h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce animate__delay-2s animate__infinite">Lorem, ipsum dolor</h1>` Las clases deben que dar asi.

Comment: Para hacer funcionar su codigo solo añadi esas clases y funciono. No hice otro cambio al codigo que proporciono.

Comment: Que extraño Entonces Usiel, Sera porque hice el NPM install y tambien añadi la biblioteca?

Comment: Si, prueba solo con el CDN.